# TMPro is a namespace but used like a type Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

All the threads I've found speak about static classes when this is not. I created a Text Mesh Pro Game Object, and in a separate script wanted to toggle it on and off on press. The title is what the console says, why is this invalid?

```
 public class Surprise : MonoBehaviour
 {
   public TMPro textBox;
    
   void Start()
   {
      textBox.SetActive(false);
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Show us the declaration for `TMPro`.

Comment: In Unity I made a Text Mesh Pro object, I didn't actually code it. Is that what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TMPro is a namespace, it cannot be declared as an object but its used in the using directive. However, if you just want to hide it, you can just hide the gameobject like this

```
public class Surprise : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject textbox;
    void Start() {
        textbox.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```